# Why is an expectation used instead of simple sum in GANs?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, generative-adversarial-networks

Why do the GAN's loss functions use an expectation (sum + division) instead of a simple sum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean the original loss explained in [the original GAN paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.2661.pdf). This practice was by design and for interpretation. An expectation is what your expecting to get, which is generally a good objective when your are sampling. Note this isn't just in GANs, it's in most objective functions used in a widespread of problems.

In general practice, though, dividing is good because it works as a normalization. Let's say you train one batch with 10 elements and the next with 8. Wouldn't you want each training example to be weighted equally?

Also, even if you use equal-sized batches, then the "division" you mention gets eaten up by the learning rate if you're using some form of gradient scheme.